# Graph theory and trees

Tags: graph-theory

Let T be a tree with n vertices,where n greater than or equal to 3.Show that there is a vertex V in T with d(V) greater than or equal to 2 such that every vertex adjacent to V ,except possibly for one ,has degree 1.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T’$ be a subgraph of $T$ induced by the set of all vertices of $T$ which have degree at least $2$. Since $T$ is connected and $n\ge 3$, $T’$ is non-empty. Since $T’$ is a subgraph of a tree, it is forest, that is a union of mutually disjoint trees. Choose any of these trees and pick as the required vertex $v$ any its leaf, that is a vertex of degree $1$.